# Como exibir uma Lista Circular Duplamente Encadeada

Tags: c++

Como faço pra exibir os valores inseridos em uma Lista Circular Duplamente Encadeada?

Segue o meu código com minha tentativa:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

int x, num;

struct lista
{
    int valor;
    struct lista * prox;
    struct lista * ant;
};

struct lista * inicio;
struct lista * fim;
struct lista * aux;

//Insere na lista o número passado por parãmetro
void insere(int valor)
{
    aux = (struct lista *)malloc(sizeof(struct lista));
    aux->valor = valor;
    aux->prox = NULL;
    aux->ant = NULL;

    if (inicio == NULL)
    {
        inicio = aux;
    }
    else
    {
        fim->prox = aux;
        aux->ant = fim;
    }
    fim = aux;
    fim->prox;
    inicio->ant = fim;
}

//Mostra todos os elementos da lista
void exibirElementos()
{ 
    while (1)
    {
        cout << inicio->valor;
        inicio->prox;
        if (inicio->prox->valor == fim->valor)
            break;
    }
}

int main()
{
    inicio = NULL;
    fim = NULL;
    aux = NULL;
}
```

O método que está responsável por mostrar os valores é `exibirElementos()`.

Estou usando o *Visual Studio 2013* para compilar.

Comment: posso postar um pseudo-código?

Comment: @EnzoTiezzi Pode sim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiro, coloque a assinatura do método `exibirElementos1` logo após a declaração da `struct lista`
`void exibirElementos1(struct lista * node);`

Faça uma função recursiva que irá passar por sua lista toda da seguinte maneira.

```
    void exibirElementos()
    {
        exibirElementos1(&inicio);
    }

    void exibirElementos1(lista *node)
    {
        if (node != null)
        {
            cout<<node->valor
            exibirElementos1(&node->prox);
        }
    }
```

Dessa maneira ele começa pelo primeiro nodo na sua lista, tendo que você tem um nodo declarado com o nome `inicio`, e para exatamente no ultimo nodo da sua lista imprimindo todos na tela.

E de forma iterativa

```
    void exibirElementosIterativo(lista* node)
    {
        while (node != NULL)
        {
            cout << node->valor;
            node = node->prox;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Desse jeito ta dando erro, está falando que o método não precisa de argumentos. `'exibirElementos()':function does not take 1 arguments`

Comment: atualiza o código pra eu ver como você fez

Comment: eu editei ali, mudei o nome do segundo método `exibirElementos` para `exibirElementos1`.

Comment: Pergunta atualizada

Comment: continua apresentando o mesmo problema ? editei novamente, da uma olhada agora

Comment: Agora está dando outro problema: `'exibirElementos1': identifier not found`. Não está achando a função dentro do método `exibirElementos()`

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discuss&#227;o no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18762/discussion-between-enzo-tiezzi-and-exception).